# General Template for Binary Semaphore with processes

Tags: linux, operating-system, semaphore

I am learning semaphores, and wanted to try out semaphore IPC on a shared memory program I have implemented before. (The program involves sharing the Shared Memory between parent and child process: Reading and writing it etc). When I use a variable and increment it in Parent and decrement it in child, due to Race condition I get unexpected output. So i wanted to synchronize the two using Semaphore. But I needed a starting point, a template to begin with.
I have done the previous shared memory example using such template (initializing,attaching,detaching etc) I found else where. So if anyone can suggest some steps...

What I am trying:

```
struct shmarea    // My shared Memory
{
  ` unsigned long count;
};    
struct shmarea *shma;

main()
{
  id =  shmget(KEY1,4096,IPC_CREAT|0600);
  shma = shmat(id,0,0); 
  shma->count = 0;
  ret = fork();

 if(ret>0)
 {    
 printf("in parent .. ppid is %lu ...and pid is %lu\n",getppid(),getpid()); 
 sleep(5);
 while(j++ < 2147483645){  // The large loop is to See the processes in top command
 while(i++ < 2147483645) shma->count++;   
     }

 }
 if(ret==0)
 {     
    printf("in child .. ppid is %lu ...and pid is %lu\n",getppid(),getpid());       
    while(j++ < 2147483645){
        while(i++ < 2147483645) shma->count--;
    }   
    exit(0); 
 }

 if(ret>0)
 {
    //Clean up
 }
}
```

I did look for Semaphore creation examples..But mostly I am stuck with use of semaphore sets..How to map it with binary semaphore...because in this simple program i just need to have two values 0 and 1.